# Know if IActivity is from bot or user in IActivityLogger

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to implement `IActivityLogger` and perform different actions depending on if the bot is the sender of the activity or a user is the sender.

How do I know if the activity is from the bot or the user. Can I get the bot's channel id somewhere to compare it to the Id in `Activity.From.Id` or is there a different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a static dictionary of ChannelId / BotId (Recipient.Id) that you can fill in your `MessagesController` every time a new message arrives. At that time, you know that `activity.Recipient.Id` will be the bot and then use `activity.ChannelId` to get the channel id that will be the key of your dictionary.

After that, you can use that dictionary in your `IActivityLogger` to do the check of the id.

Comment: Thank you, don't know why I didn't think of that. Guess I was looking for a solution that didn't require any bookkeeping like a `ChannelUser.IsBot` property ;-)